Docker for Python, connect with AWS Ecr credentials
i would like to connect to ECR private repositories using the Docker Python SDK with custom AWS credentials, so i need to pass them when configuring my client, but i cannot understand how.
I tried to instantiate the docker client in this way
config = { "ServerURL": "xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", "Username": getApplicationValue("aws.username"), "Secret": getApplicationValue("aws.password"), } client = docker.DockerClient(credstore_env=config)
But when trying to pull an image, i see it tries to pull from docker hub
image = client.images.pull(repository="repo", tag="latest")
This is the exception
docker.errors.ImageNotFound: 404 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.47/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=repo: Not Found ("pull access denied for repo, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied")

I cannot use the aws boto3 library because it does not have the pull command
How do i need to create the docker client to pass credentials to it?
